# Show student_name on submission show table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I need to show the student name that I selected in the submission form through a dropdown in my show submission table.

show submission:

```
<h1><%= @form.title %></h1>
<p>
  <%= image_tag @form.image.url(:medium) %>
</p>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if @submissions.blank? %>
      <h4>No submission just yet</h4>
    <% else %>
    <thead>
      <th>Conflict</th>
      <th>Computer</th>
      <th>Extra time</th>
      <th>AM or PM</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= submission.conflict %></td>
          <td><%= submission.computer %></td>
          <td><%= submission.extra_time %>%</td>
          <td><%= submission.am_pm %></td>
          <td><%= submission.student.id %></td>
          <!-- Need to add Edit, Delete -->
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Submission', new_form_submission_path(@form) %>
<br>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_form_path(@form) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', forms_path %>
```

submission form:

```
<%= form_for([@form, @submission]) do |f| %>
<% if @submission.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@submission.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this submission from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @submission.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :conflict %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :conflict, :Yes, required: :true %> Yes<br>
    <%= f.radio_button :conflict, :No, required: :true %> No
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :computer %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :computer, :Yes, required: :true %> Yes<br>
    <%= f.radio_button :computer, :No, required: :true %> No
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :am_pm %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :am_pm, :Am, required: :true %> Am<br>
    <%= f.radio_button :am_pm, :Pm, required: :true %> Pm
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Student" %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:student, :student_id, Student.all, :id, :student_name, prompt: true) %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :extra_time %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :extra_time, 25, required: :true %> 25%<br>
    <%= f.radio_button :extra_time, 50, required: :true %> 50%
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

submission_controller.rb:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_submission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_form

  # GET /submissions/new
  def new
    @submission = Submission.new
  end

  # GET /submissions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /submissions
  # POST /submissions.json
  def create
    @submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
    @submission.form_id = @form.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.save
        format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Submission was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @submission }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /submissions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /submissions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.update(submission_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /submissions/1
  # DELETE /submissions/1.json
  def destroy
    @submission.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to submissions_url, notice: 'Submission was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_submission
      @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_form
      @form = Form.find(params[:form_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def submission_params
      params.require(:submission).permit(:conflict, :computer, :extra_time, :am_pm)
    end
end
```

student_controller.rb:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /students
  # GET /students.json
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /students/new
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  # GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /students/1
  # PATCH/PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update(student_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /students/1
  # DELETE /students/1.json
  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to students_url, notice: 'Student was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:student_name)
    end
end
```

submission.rb:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  has_one :student
end
```

student.rb:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
end
```

The problem is that if I try to see the last submission in the console, there is nothing that correlates to the username I chose.

Thanks

Comment: Add your  association also.

Comment: Your `show` page has a line `<td><%= submission.student.id %></td>`, if that is working, why you are not trying `<%= submission.student.name %>`. Assuming, `name` is an attribute of `Student`.

Comment: @dp7 both of them are not working

Comment: @GiovanniPecchio You need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in Submission model for students. Just have a look at the documentation, you will get idea how to proceed further.

Comment: @dp7 I trying everything that I can find on the internet, but I don't get if I have to add something to my controllers or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

When you created your submission, did you create a student_id in your migration?

An example would be when creating your scaffold:

```
rails g Scaffold Student student_name:string submission:references
```

This should link your submission and student

Comment: I created a scaffold student with student_name and student_id

Comment: Im not sure how you intend to build your application, but it would make more sense to have a student which has_many :submissions and submission belongs to a user. This would make more sense.